# What is the velocity of an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider an orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ so that$\boldsymbol{A}^T \boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{A}^T = \boldsymbol{I}$. Suppose this matrix can vary with time, hence denoting it as $\boldsymbol{A}(t)$. I would like to obtain the velocity matrix $\frac{d}{d t} \boldsymbol{A}(t)$, which I denote as $\dot{\boldsymbol{A}}$.

The conditions that $\dot{\boldsymbol{A}}$ needs to satisfy can be easily obtained by differentiating all sides of the identity $\boldsymbol{A}^T \boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{A}^T = \boldsymbol{I}$ with respect to $t$:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{A}^T \dot{\boldsymbol{A}} + \dot{\boldsymbol{A}}^T \boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{A} \dot{\boldsymbol{A}}^T + \dot{\boldsymbol{A}} \boldsymbol{A}^T = \boldsymbol{O}
\end{equation}
This essentially gives a linear system that $\dot{\boldsymbol{A}}$ needs to satisfy. My question is, whether the solution $\dot{\boldsymbol{A}}$ has a nice closed form expression in terms of $\boldsymbol{A}$ or its elements.

Thank you!

Golabi

Comment: It is an interesting question for a lot of reasons, for example it is used to define what is a tangent vector to the Lie Group of orthogonal matrices. In that case for instance we assume $A(0)=\mathbb{I}$ matrix and from this follows that, the matrix $\dot{A}(0)$ is skew-symmetric, i.e. $\dot{A}(0)\in \text{skew}(n)$. It was just a comment but I don't know how to answer to your question in full generality.

Comment: My intuition on this is no. As @Dadeslam noted, the tangent space to the Orthogonal Group at $I$ is the space of skew-symmetric matrices. So suppose you have $A(t)$ as Dadeslam noted, where $A(0) = I$. Then this is a curve in the manifold $O(n)$. It is known that for any tangent vector $X$ at any point $p$, there is a smooth curve passing through $p$ whose velocity is $X$ at $p$. Thus $A'(0)$ could be any skew-symmetric matrix, so how would we derive one from $A(0) = I$? I recommend Tu's _Introduction to Manifolds_, esp. $\S$15 on Lie Groups & Algebras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having reflected more on my comments, I think I can formulate this as an answer: No.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of smooth curves through the manifold of $O(n)$ of of orthogonal $n\times n$ matrices (i.e. time dependent orthogonal matrices, as in your question) such that for all $A \in \mathcal{A},$ $A(0) = I$. It can be shown that the tangent space to $I \in O(n)$ is the space of skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

It is known from the theory of smooth manifolds (see Tu, *An Introduction to Manifolds,* Prop. 8.16) that for every tangent vector $X$ at a point $p$ in a smooth manifold, there exists (locally) a smooth curve through $p$ whose velocity at $p$ is $X$. This means that for **every** skew-symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $B$, we can find $A(t) \in \mathcal{A}$ such that  $\dot A(0) = B$. However, as defined above, $A(0) = I$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Therefore, there can be no prescriptive formula which determines $\dot A(0)$ in terms of $A(0) = I$.

Now, if we allow ourselves to consider the functions of $t$ for each matrix element of $A(t)$, since we cannot just use the values of these functions at a time $t$ to find $\dot A$ at $t$ as I have just shown, the only other logical option here is use a derivative of these functions. However, then we have a fairly easy and completely tautological answer:

$$
\dot A(t) = (\dot a_{ij}(t))_{ij} = \dot A(t).
$$